# Entity Framework generating separate classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, code-generation

I was using previous versions of entity framework and it was generating just one file for all classes . But I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 and now it generates a separate class files for each table . How do I change that ? I don't want 100s of class files and want them to be combined in one file/namespace .

Comment: Are you sure you want this instead of a nicely ordered hierarchy? It will be a pain to find something in the document, let alone work fluently with it. As far as I know, what you're asking isn't possible.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx  ... have fun... i think you're crazy ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove your T4 Templates (the `*.tt` files) an all the generate classes. Then open the `*.edmx` file. In the property window search for `Code Generation Strategy` and set it from `None` to `Default`.
Now the old template with the `ObjectContext` will be generatet. But I recommend using the T4 Template and its generated POCO classes. Thei're much cleaner and you can change the T4 template if needed.

See 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13614390/2743414

And [How can I modify the default code generation strategy for edmx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900231/how-can-i-modify-the-default-code-generation-strategy-for-edmx)

Comment: It can be done without deleting of any files. Just open `edmx` file, find the `<edmx:DesignerProperty Name="CodeGenerationStrategy"` and change its `Value` to `"Default"`.